# service task stuck at pending status in aws ecs fargate when pushing docker image from visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-toolkit

I am trying to push Aspnet core project into AWS ECS Fargate from Visual Studio using AWS Tootkit following this AWS [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHg0EnmRztE&t=319s).

[image]

The pushing docker image and ECS fargate registeration is successful however the task is at PENDING status.

[image]

ECS Cluster: my-cluster:

[image]

Any idea please to debug please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Task to see more info:

```
Status reason   CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: Get https://xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Assign Public IP Address to allow Task to pull docker image from outside:

[image]